# Error: variable '*' has initializer but incomplete type and one other

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

I know there are a couple other questions on this specific question, but nothing that I can find on it seems to work, so I'm posting my specific code.

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef __MEMORY_TRACKER_H__
#define __MEMORY_TRACKER_H__

#include <unordered_map>

namespace cige
{
namespace memory
{
class CIGE_API MemoryTracker
{
protected:
typedef struct AllocRecord
{
    size_t bytes;
    std::string filename;
    size_t line;
    std::string func;

    AllocRecord() :
        bytes(0), line(0)
    { }
    AllocRecord(size_t sz, const char* file, size_t ln, const char* fun) :
        bytes(sz), line(ln)
    {
        if (file)
            filename = file;
        if (fun)
            func = fun;
    }
} AllocRecord;

std::string m_leakFileName;
bool m_dumpToConsole;
typedef std::unordered_map<void*, AllocRecord> AllocMap;
AllocMap m_allocationMap;

size_t m_totalAllocations;
bool m_recordEnable;

protected:
void reportLeaks();

MemoryTracker() :
    m_leakFileName("CIGEMemory.log"), m_dumpToConsole(true), m_totalAllocations(0), m_recordEnable(true)
{ }

public:
void setReportFileName(const std::string& name)
{
    m_leakFileName = name;
}
const std::string& getReportFileName() const
{
    return m_leakFileName;
}
void setReportToConsoleOutput(bool b)
{
    m_dumpToConsole = b;
}
bool getReportToConsoleOutput() const
{
    return m_dumpToConsole;
}
void setRecordEnable(bool b)
{
    m_recordEnable = b;
}
bool getRecordEnable() const
{
    return m_recordEnable;
}

size_t getTotalMemoryAllocated() const
{
    return m_totalAllocations;
}

void _recordAlloc(void* ptr, size_t sz, const char* file = nullptr, size_t ln = 0, const char* fun = nullptr);
void _recordDealloc(void* ptr);

~MemoryTracker()
{
    reportLeaks();
}

static MemoryTracker& get();
};
}
}

#endif // __MEMORY_TRACKER_H__
```

I'm getting: `variable 'cige::memory::CIGE_API cige::memory::MemoryTracker' has initializer but incomplete type` at the line with the class declaration. I've looked all over and I cant find any answers that have fixed this issue.

I'm also having the error `expected '}' or ',' or ';' before 'protected'` at the line with protected, right above the struct.

Any help with either of these two errors would be appreciated.

EDIT: CIGE_API is defined in a separate file (which is included), as `__declspec(dllexport)`.

EDIT2: I fixed my problem (see the answer below). It was basically just Code::Blocks derping out pretty bad.

Comment: Side remark: your include guard names are invalid in C++ since names starting with underscores, or a single underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementer of the compiler / standard library. Also, `typedef struct` makes no sense in C++. And third, how’s CIGE_API defined? According to the error message, its definition is probably missing.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks, and I included a separate file with a bunch of standard defines using C::B's setting to globally include files. CIGE_API is defined as __declspec(dllexport).

Comment: Also, @KonradRudolph, those include guards are perfectly valid, as I've never had any problems with them before on the many projects I've used with both MSVC and MinGW. Its also the same include guards that the Ogre Engine uses, and they seem to have never had any problems with it either.

Comment: They are most assuredly **not** valid. Just because you haven’t had a problem yet doesn’t mean anything. And just because some other code does it doesn’t mean it’s not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `CIGE_API` is not defined. So compiler try to resolve it like variable declaration `class Type Variable {initializer-list}`, where `Type` is `CIGE_API` and `Variable` is `MemoryTracker`.

In other words, syntactically you're predeclaring `CIGE_API` type and creating variable of this type instead of defining a class.

Answer (score 1):

The definition

```
class CIGE_API MemoryTracker { ... };
```

is not valid C++. I guess `CIGE_API` is a macro defined to an implementation specific extension, but you didn't include the corresponding header which defines that macro.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up fixing my own problem. Code::Blocks wasn't properly finding files that were in my project (about the third time this has happened).

In entirely unrelated news, does anyone know another cross-platform IDE that works well for C++? (I already know about Eclipse).

Comment: I recommend QtCreator